# Listview in the ListViewFragment is not appearing in the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the `activity_main.xml` with one `FrameLayout` relative to a `ListViewFragment`. I want to show this `fragment` in this `activity`. But its not working the `ListView` is not appearing. Do you know where is the issue?

**main activity xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_list"
 />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Main activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // here Im trying to add the fragment A to the activity but the listview is not appearing
        getSupportFragmentManager().
                beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_list,new ListViewFragment()).commit();

    }
}
```

**listview xml:**

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

**ListViewFragment:**

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView editor=null;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        editor=(ListView) (result.findViewById(R.id.listView));
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        editor.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add height and width to the framelayout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_list" />
```

Also your listView Fragment cannot have listview as parent layout.So wrap it with a layout like frame layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but the listview also dont appears.

Comment: Updated answer.Check it.